# How to center child entity on instantiation

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have setup a test case for the problem I am having at [this glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/wordvom?path=test2/index.html).

Essentially, on each click I am trying to create a sphere, with a text-geometry child where the text is centered on the sphere, i.e. "X marks the spot".

What is happening is the first time I click, the text is oriented so the bottom left aligns with the sphere.

I try and use geometry.center() to fix this, but there appears to be no bounding box available.

I have it setup to do this in a component, when loaded, and when object3dset, but none of these work.

If I click again and use getElementById() to get the existing text-geometry, then call geometry.center() it actually centers.

My hunch is that for some reason I can't discern, the bounding box isn't created until later, but I can't find out when.

Any insight into how to how I can get this centered with just one click would be great, thanks.

EDIT:  I should note that I have found using a setTimeout (as commented out on the glitch) will cause it to work, so it definitely seems to be a problem of when things happen, but that's not really a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

> I try and use geometry.center() to fix this, but there appears to be no bounding box available.

Run `geometry.computeBoundingBox()`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The bounding box is created, but the size in all dimensions is 0.  It isn't until the second click (or a small delay) that the box is actually the size of the text-geometry.

The

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on where exactly you want the text placed when you say centered on the sphere, but on the assumption that you are setting the radius of the sphere, you then know exactly where the bounds of the sphere will be regardless of bounding box computation, and the a-text component for example has parameters that will allow you to center the text and align to top and bottom; you can use the zOffset parameter to prevent the text from being inside the sphere, for example.  For arbitrary shapes you would probably need to wait for the shape geometry to be generated and bounding box to be available.

Comment: > For arbitrary shapes you would probably need to wait for the shape geometry to be generated and bounding box to be available.

I am pretty sure this is the case.  It isn't using a-text, but rather text-geometry, which is creating a new THREE.TextGeometry.  I am now thinking that is just taking some time because the implemented timeout is pretty reliable even though it looks glitchy.

Now that I have done a little more testing I think it's really a problem of not having the mesh.getWorldPosition set.  Is there a way to listen to an event for when the entire entity is added to the scene?

Comment: This shows what I mean (w/ debug logging on the console)

https://wordvom.glitch.me/test2

Uncommenting the setTimeout block at line 109 causes it to work on the first click.